# Применяется ли где то ByteArray в сигнатуре метода java, kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, java-8

Используют ли где-то ByteArray как параметр функции? У меня был контракт, где клиент принимал ByteArray, я в своем методе тоже передаю ByteArray, на что мне было замечание, что нигде в библиотеках так не используют, нужно InputStream, да, это интерфейс, на абстракциях правильнее, но насколько это критично? И может все таки где то используют в библиотеках на вход ByteArray?

Comment: Смотря что там передаете, известно-ли заранее что это 10 байт или содержимое файла, в первом случае ByteArray будет Ок, во втором скорее InputStream.

Comment: Да, известно, что будет файл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замечание справедливое: `ByteArray` плох тем, что не ограничивает размер буфера, поэтому легко можно схватить переполнение кучи.

> Да, известно, что будет файл

А если файл размером в 1гб? Что тогда? Будет больно...

С другой стороны есть туча разных библиотек, фреймворков, которые вполне нормально живут и без `InputStream` - далеко ходить не будем и возьмем к примеру [SQLDelight](https://github.com/cashapp/sqldelight) - живет без `InputStream` - работа с байтовыми массивами построена на `ByteArray` - что не очень хорошо.